# How do I call a person who's having a 1 on 1 conversation with me

Tags: terminology

*Participant* sounds like one of many people in a group conversation.
I want to know the equivalent of that word in a 1 on 1 conversation.

Comment: You could opt for "interlocutor" although it's a bit heavy. (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interlocutor)

Comment: If its a philosophical discussion and they're holding a different view: disputant, opponent, sparring partner, etc.  But in general, there's probably no common word for this. i.e. interlocutor is more likely to be found in some scholarly work than in every day conversation (unless its being used humorously).

Comment: How much are you monopolizing the conversation?  Is that other guy the "listener"?

Comment: @developerwjk In that case why not "the person I was speaking to"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with the comments of @RonaldSole and @WS2, each of which points to *interlocutor* as a solid answer to the OP's question.

From Merriam-Webster:

[*interlocutor*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interlocutor): a person who is having a conversation with you

Answer (score 4):

Though it often has a more specific meaning for language learners participating in a language exchange, the term "**conversation partner**" can be used to refer to the other party in a one-on-one conversation.

Here's an example of it in use:

> There are times when a conversation just doesn't seem to click. My **conversation partner** and I are not picking up on each other's cues. There's door after door that I do not wish to open. Well, I can certainly opt out and find a more palatable **conversation partner**. If social circumstances do not permit such an exit, I can always choose to converse about the present.

[[Source](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=E8ppaisxKK4C&pg=PT42&lpg=PT42&dq=%22my+conversation+partner%22&source=bl&ots=syOdGh6ECH&sig=TGHIwDjLyIg1Rwu7u1Gs70IHgI8&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22my%20conversation%20partner%22&f=false): *Infectious: How to Connect Deeply and Unleash the Energetic Leader Within* by Achim Nowak]

Answer (score 3):

The term *counterpart* is used when two parties are in an interaction like negotiation, collaboration, dispute, or conflict.

- I am negotiating on behalf of my company with the union. She is my counterpart negotiating on behalf of the union.
- I have been engaged intimately in a rather fruitful relationship for the last few weeks. I am trying my best to soften the shock that your estranged husband is my counterpart in this relationship. But don't worry, I was not his counterpart that had seduced him to ruin your marriage last year.
- This will not be a free-for-all debate. Each one of you will debate only the assigned counterpart on the other team.
- Every morning he gets up at 7 am, makes two cups of coffee to bring them to the park to meet his nemesis and counterpart in a game of chess.
- She is schizo. She talks to herself. Correction, she talks to someone that exists only in her mind. Her counterpart in her conversations has the name Mary.

---

[counterpart](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/counterpart) (ˈkaʊntəˌpɑːt)

n

1. a person or thing identical to or closely resembling another
2. one of two parts that complement or correspond to each other
3. (Theatre) a person acting opposite another in a play
4. (Law) a duplicate, esp of a legal document; copy

*Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014 © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2011, 2014*

Answer (score 3):

The OP is having a *tête-à-tête* with his interlocutor and vice-versa. I believe that that the French expression *tête-à-tête* would cover the two people involved in the OP's "1 on 1 conversation".

This is a French expression whose word-for-word literal translation is simply head-to-head. I consider its contemporary use in English to be archaic and pretentious but it still crops up in 19th & 20th century English literature and would have been used in conversation by the minority of English speakers who like to make use of foreign words in their English language discourse.

> **tête-à-tête:** A private conversation between two persons. (M-W)
>   Origin & Etymology: French, literally, head-to-head. First known use [in English]: 1696. (M-W).